# Is it possible to configure a container from docker-compose or some other way?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Is it somehow possible to pass commands for automated container configuration, after the container has been started? For instance, could I pass multiple commands to the container to restart services with systemctl, change network configs, chmod files, etc, from docker-compose?

Thanks.

Comment: How would you do this with the same process but not in a container?  For example, say you ran `nginx` in a terminal window; what changes would you try to make to that _process_, that you're trying to replicate in an `nginx` Docker container?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can change the startup script to do what you want. Or you could run an init container or possibly in your dockerfile when you make the container.

Comment: You should give an exmaple or a pointer on how to do that exactly.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on those options? "startup script" referring to bashrc? What is an init container? I'm finding info about init containers in relation to Kubernetes Pods, but not Docker containers.

Comment: Sorry, init container will not work, that is only for k8s. Yes startup script is bashrc. How do you make your image?